# Многопоточное приложение

Tags: python, python-3.x

С помощью какого модуля лучше все организовать отдельный поток, который будет асинхронно через определенный интервал времени обновлять данные в родительском потоке до явной его остановки? Желательно с примером

Comment: Выбрал для себя threading.Thread с setDaemon(True) . Насколько это оправданно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как в 3.2 но в 2.х для достижения многопоточности(которое работало асинхронно) требовалось использовать multiprocessing.

ЗЫ

[Подробнее о том почему не threading](http://habrahabr.ru/post/167733/)

[Неплохое чтиво, будет полезно](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/)